# Regex to match all occurrences but ignore if it starts with vendor

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I'm trying to do a regex to match to find and match all `anystring/css/` except `vendor/css/` for example

```
apples/css/
vendor/css/
kiwi/css/
Apple/css/
vendor/css/
```

should match

```
apples/css/
kiwi/css/
Apple/css/
```

i was able to come up with but its not working correctly and only ignores the first `vendor/css/` but not the others

```
\b[^(vendor)].+\/css\/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^(vendor)]` means any character that is not one of `(`, `v`, `e`, `n`, `d`, `o`, `r`, `)`. This wouldn't work as you expected.

To match directories (?) that doesn't start with a folder named `vendor`, use negative lookahead:

```
\b            # Match a word boundary, then
(?!vendor\/)  #                        start with 'vendor/',
.+            # anything that does not
\/css\/       # followed by '/css/'.
```

This matches:

```
apples/css/
kiwi/css/
Apple/css/
endor/css/
venv/css/
foo/bar/css/
lorem/css/ipsum/css/

dolor/sit/amet/vendor/css/
vendors/css/
baz/css/qux
```

...but not:

```
vendor/css/
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fA84GT/1).

To limit the whole line to two levels, use:

```
^             # At the beginning of line, match a string that
(?!vendor\/)  # is not 'vendor/',
[^\/]+\/      # and consists of 1+ non-slash characters, then a slash,
css\/         # followed by 'css/'
$             # right before the end of line.
```

This matches:

```
apples/css/
kiwi/css/
Apple/css/
endor/css/
venv/css/
vendors/css/
```

...but not:

```
foo/bar/css/
lorem/css/ipsum/css/
dolor/sit/amet/vendor/css/
baz/css/qux
vendor/css/
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fA84GT/2).